# AddHandler for Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: vb.net, vpn, addhandler

I'm trying to create code to auto detect a drop in VPN connection and general internet connection (as well as when it reconnects to both).

I've tried AddHandler with the VpnApiClass (every action in intellisense) and NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged. NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged works for internet dropping, but not if just the VPN drops.

```
    '''''VB.NET:
    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim tmpVpn as New NpnApiClass

       AddHandler tmpVpn.VpnStateNotification, AddressOf NetworkConnectionChanged
       AddHandler tmpVpn.VpnEventAvailableNotification, AddressOf NetworkConnectionChanged
       AddHandler NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged, AddressOf NetworkConnectionChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub NetworkConnectionChanged()
       '''''Note: CommonElements is a dll file I'm referencing, function returns a boolean (True if connected, False if disconnected).
       If Not CommonElements.isConnectedToNetwork_NetworkInterface() Then
           Main.AddFiles.Enabled = False
           Main.RemoveFiles.Enabled = False
           Status.Text = "Disconnected"
       Else
           Main.AddFiles.Enabled = True
           Main.RemoveFiles.Enabled = True
           Status.Text = "Connected"
       End If
    End Sub
```

Expecting to see buttons on main form disable buttons and update the status label text when disconnected from VPN. Then enable buttons and update the status label text when reconnected to VPN. Instead it doesn't update anything short of pulling the ethernet cord from my laptop. No errors or unhandled exceptions.